# Why do I get " PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/homeless-shelter'Q when installing 'jina-hubble-sdk' with Nix Flake

Tags: nix, nix-flake

To build a my virtual environment with a nix flake, I have to add some python packages that are not in the nix package manager. I have a problem installing  "jina-hubble-sdk"

I run

```
nix develop
```

in the directory containing flake.nix that looks like that:

```
{  description = "Python environment with ollama";

 inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

 outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils, ... }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system: let
      pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
      
      # Define Python package jina-hubble-sdk
      jina-hubble-sdk = with pkgs.python3Packages;
        buildPythonPackage rec {
          pname = "jina-hubble-sdk";
          version = "0.39.0";

          src = pkgs.fetchPypi {
            inherit pname version;
            sha256 = "9021417794a6d3cf3fad8a880cf668a3a986b9d53d5be5fa391aae1767a5b9b0";
          };

          nativeBuildInputs = [
          ];

          propagatedBuildInputs = [
            pip
            requests
            aiohttp
            rich
            importlib-metadata
            filelock
            pathspec
            docker
            pyyaml
            python-jose
          ];
        };
   
      # Define Python environment with necessary packages
      pythonEnv = pkgs:
        pkgs.python3.withPackages (ps:
          with ps; [
             jina-hubble-sdk # Include jina in the environment
          ]);
    in {
      devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
        buildInputs = with pkgs; [
          curl
          (pythonEnv pkgs)
        ];
      };
    }); }
```

and I get the following error message:

> error: builder for
> '/nix/store/d4ncmq68cjksfzdhz2klsrr1wm5jm9aj-python3.11-jina-hubble-sdk-0.39.0.drv'
> failed with exit code 1;
> last 10 log lines:
> >     os.mkdir(self, mode)
> > PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/homeless-shelter'
> >
> >
> > ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> > Ran 1 test in 0.002s
> >
> > FAILED (errors=1)
> > Test failed: <unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=1 errors=1 failures=0>
> > error: Test failed: <unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=1 errors=1 failures=0>
> For full logs, run 'nix-store -l /nix/store/d4ncmq68cjksfzdhz2klsrr1wm5jm9aj-python3.11-jina-hubble-sdk-0.39.0.drv'.
> error: 1 dependencies of derivation
> '/nix/store/5p0ffk9xjmb3zx73d1gzab0pjngmasbh-python3-3.11.8-env.drv'
> failed to build error: 1 dependencies of derivation
> '/nix/store/g9qd2rvp2fkbz47mzbjnqzlfnkk6hvjm-nix-shell-env.drv' failed
> to build

It come from jina-hubble-sdk-0.39.0.drv. I read this [message](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/12591) that speak about a problem similar and speak about HOME and TMPDIR. Thefore I give you their value in a similar environment that the environment I want to create.

```
$HOME
```

> bash: /home/nixos: Is a directory

```
$TMPDIR
```

> bash: /tmp/nix-shell.QHZzjA: Is a directory

Comment: Builds happen in a sandbox; they can't change anything outside that sandbox, so they don't have valid home directories; for this reason, the home directory you have set outside is not copied into the environment which runs the build. You can of course set HOME _yourself_ from inside the code doing the build, pointing it to a location that's writable from the sandbox -- `HOME=$PWD` is a very common practice.

Comment: (btw, any reason you're running `$HOME` instead of something like `echo "$HOME"` or `declare -p HOME` or the like?)

Comment: ...to be clear, though, again: you need to change the value of HOME _in the derivation running the build_, not in your personal shell. `/home/nixos` is certainly not the value of HOME in the builder -- the builder uses `/homeless-shelter` specifically. This isolation prevents details of the environment of the user who requested the build from seeping into the software being built.

Comment: Try reading `nix show-derivation /nix/store/d4ncmq68cjksfzdhz2klsrr1wm5jm9aj-python3.11-jina-hubble-sdk-0.39.0.drv` if you want to see the environment variables and build steps used during the specific build that's failing.

Comment: As a side note, you do not need `poetry-core` as build inputs for this Python package as it is not packaged with Poetry.

Comment: @charlesDuffy. I ve no particuliar reason to run  $HOME over the other. Except that is slightly shorter

Comment: @LoïcReynier You re right. You know it comes from a copy paste of another python package created with peotry. I will remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As highlighted in Charles Duffy's comments, adjusting the `$HOME` variable is required within the build process, not in your environment.

In `nixpkgs` when a package build needs a writable home, we usually use `export HOME=$(mktemp -d)`. To avoid conflicting with the pre-configured `buildPhase` for Python packages, you should export your variable in the `preBuild` phase:

```hs
src = { ... };

preBuild = ''
  export HOME=$(mktemp -d)
'';

nativeBuildInputs = [ ... ];
```

Comment: you can see a full version of this your solution there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78183326/how-to-fix-nix-build-failure-due-to-a-file-using-the-windows-way-to-break-line. (I used preConfig but when I tested that made no difference) It still doesn't work but for a different reason.

Comment: FYI, you can skip the `export` -- setting a new value to any variable already in the environment, that value is exported automatically; so just `HOME=$(mktemp -d)` suffices. (That said, I prefer `HOME=$PWD` in Nix derivations -- reduces the chances of that change of the temporary directory sneaking into your builds and breaking binary reproducibility).