# How to fix Nix build failure due to a file using the windows way to break line

Tags: nix, nix-flake

I am running NixOS on WSL

I use nix version nix 2.18.1
I run

```
 nix develop
```

in the directory containing flake.nix that looks like that:

```
{
 description = "Python environment with ollama";

 inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
 inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

 outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils, ... }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system: let
      pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
      
      jina-hubble-sdk = with pkgs.python3Packages;
        buildPythonPackage rec {
          pname = "jina-hubble-sdk";
          version = "0.39.0";

          src = pkgs.fetchPypi {
            inherit pname version;
            sha256 = "9021417794a6d3cf3fad8a880cf668a3a986b9d53d5be5fa391aae1767a5b9b0";
          };

          nativeBuildInputs = [
            poetry-core
            pkgs.dos2unix # Add dos2unix to convert line endings
          ];

          propagatedBuildInputs = [
            pep517
            pip
            requests
            aiohttp
            rich
            importlib-metadata
            filelock
            pathspec
            docker
            pyyaml
            python-jose
          ];
          

          # Convert line endings to Unix-style
          preConfigure = ''
            export HOME=$(mktemp -d)
          '';
             # put this code inside preConfigure if you want to run it dos2unix -f /nix/store/v099hqvw5z87423p4hz1vfhzaqa07dii-stdenv-linux/setup
        };
   
      pythonEnv = pkgs:
        pkgs.python3.withPackages (ps:
          with ps; [
             jina-hubble-sdk
          ]);
    in {
      devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
        buildInputs = with pkgs; [
          curl
          ollama
          (pythonEnv pkgs)
        ];
      };
    });
}
```

and I get the following error

> error: builder for
> '/nix/store/dm6cxw020s7whbfgqj8jivd3dv1pby0i-python3.11-jina-hubble-sdk-0.39.0.drv'
> failed with exit code 127;
> last 10 log lines:
> > Using setuptoolsCheckPhase
> > Running phase: unpackPhase
> > unpacking source archive /nix/store/9q6b5l6955sabgvk8ah5xx0sfji25zmn-jina-hubble-sdk-0.39.0.tar.gz
> > source root is jina-hubble-sdk-0.39.0
> > setting SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH to timestamp 1688549032 of file jina-hubble-sdk-0.39.0/setup.cfg
> > Running phase: patchPhase
> > Running phase: updateAutotoolsGnuConfigScriptsPhase
> > Running phase: configurePhase
> > /nix/store/v099hqvw5z87423p4hz1vfhzaqa07dii-stdenv-linux/setup: line
> 114: $'\r': command not found
> > /nix/store/v099hqvw5z87423p4hz1vfhzaqa07dii-stdenv-linux/setup: line
> 131: pop_var_context: head of shell_variables not a function context
> For full logs, run 'nix-store -l /nix/store/dm6cxw020s7whbfgqj8jivd3dv1pby0i-python3.11-jina-hubble-sdk-0.39.0.drv'.
> error: 1 dependencies of derivation
> '/nix/store/25gl4f29rr56ci1h5k53wmm7wgfmk2p2-python3-3.11.8-env.drv'
> failed to build error: 1 dependencies of derivation
> '/nix/store/pxkgnl5nx66fcdi1rkvz86kbfrvlmhn2-nix-shell-env.drv' failed
> to build

The important line in the error message:

> /nix/store/v099hqvw5z87423p4hz1vfhzaqa07dii-stdenv-linux/setup: line 114: $'\r': command not found >

I supposed that the problem is linked to the different way linux and window( see this [website](https://superuser.com/questions/374028/how-are-n-and-r-handled-differently-on-linux-and-windows)) have to break a line. I wanted to adapt the file that caused a problem with:

```
   preConfigure = ''
      #   dos2unix -f /nix/store/v099hqvw5z87423p4hz1vfhzaqa07dii-stdenv-linux/setup
      # '';
```

but it change nothing. Therefore I comment it but you can uncomment it to test it yourself.

Comment: Copy-pasted your `flake.nix` and ran `nix develop .#` without error.

Comment: @LoïcReynier Ok that is very strange. I tried nix develop and nix develop .# but it doesn't work. What is your nix version? Mine is 2.18.1. (you can use this command nix --version)

Comment: Same version. You may try to update your `flake.lock` file.

Comment: @LoïcReynier I removed flake.lock and rerun flake.nix. I get the same problem. I run NixOS on WSL. Do you think this is related

Comment: Also using NixOS on WSL. Are you sure you are using the `flake.nix` from the post?

Comment: @LoïcReynier I checked again. I copy past this flake.nix in a directory, run nix develop in this same directory. And I still have the same error

Comment: @LoïcReynier these are robably silly questions but I have to try something 1) What is your value for ${system}. For me it is x86_64-linux. 2) Can you please test nix develop -i and say if it still works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the error message said that the problem comes from a file that is not the flake.nix that I developed, the problems comes from the flake.nix that I developed. I write the code using code opened from windows. Hence it use the dos encoding.

run nix develop in another directory containing this flake

```
{
 inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
 inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

 outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils, ... }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system: let
      pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
      

    in {
      devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
        buildInputs = with pkgs; [
            pkgs.dos2unix
        ];
      };
    });
}
```

You can now run

```
  dos2unix flake.nix
```

in the directory with the flake returning an error.
it changed the encoding. And you can now run

```
 nix develop
```

with this flake and it will work fine

The answer comes from
VTimofeenko who wrote it there :
https://discourse.nixos.org/t/what-could-cause-this-flake-to-fail-on-my-computer-and-succeed-on-another/41868/2